# Ошибка при реализации в своем контейнере аллокатора через allocator_traits

Tags: c++, memory-management

Всем добра.

Народ, подскажите в чем ошибка. Написал я свой аллокатор. Он работает без проблем с std::vector. Попытался я добавить уже в свой контейнер через свой же аллокатор. Получаю ошибку:

```
В конструкторе «CustomContainer<T, Allocator>::CustomContainer(CustomContainer<T, Allocator>::size_type, Allocator)»:
ошибка: qualified-id in declaration before «(» token pointer std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::allocate(count, alloc);
```

ругается он как раз на эту строку:

```
pointer std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::allocate(count, alloc);
```

Она в самом конце в приведенном ниже отрывке заголовочного файла:

```
#ifndef CUSTOM_CONTAINER_H
#define CUSTOM_CONTAINER_H

#include "CustomAllocator.h"
#include <memory>

template<class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>> 
class CustomContainer
{
 public:    
    using value_type = T;
    using alloctator_type = Allocator;
    using size_type = std::size_t;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using reference = value_type&;
    using const_reference = const value_type&;
    using pointer = typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::pointer;
    using const_pointer = typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::const_pointer;
    using void_pointer = void*;
    using const_void_pointer = const void*;    




    CustomContainer(size_type count, Allocator alloc)
    {
        pointer std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::allocate(count, alloc);
    }
```

Я тут все перелопатил что мог, но никак не пойму на что компилятор ругается.

Comment: Так а что эта строчка вообще должна означать? Что вы пытались написать? Я пока вижу какую-то синтаксическую бессмыслицу - набор слов. Компилятор тоже не понимает, что это. Моя телепатия подсказывает мне, что это попытка объявления переменной. Но где тогда имя переменной?

Comment: вызов у аллокатора allocate(). а что не так?

Comment: Вызов? И что перед эти вызовом делает слово `pointer`??? С каких это пор в С++ перед вызовом функции вдруг стали упоминать какие-то имена типов?

Comment: он же вызывает функцию возвращающую указатель. pointer, как раз, указатель. А если не правильно, то как это должно быть?

Comment: Функция `printf` возвращает `int`. Но если я хочу послать на выход строку  `"Hello World"`, я вызываю `printf("Hello World");`. Я не пишу `int printf("Hello World");`. С чего бы это? Вот и у вас - что там делает этот `pointer`??? А "как должно быть" зависит от того, что вы пытаетесь сделать. Этого вы до сих пор не объяснили. Зачем вы вызываете это `allocate`?

Comment: @el_madcapo, Вы не знаете основ синтаксиса, а уже полезли в одну из сложнейших тем, которые вообще существуют в C++. Может сначала стоит с синтаксисом разобраться?

Comment: allocate для выделения памяти под контейнер.

Comment: ваша правда. Без указания типа  все работает. Подскажите тогда, почему здесь не указывается тип. Для Вас это конечно очевидно, а для меня - нет.  Или подскажите где про этот момнет можно прочитать.

Comment: @el_madcapo, это можно прочитать в любой книге по C++. Почитайте про то, что такое переменные (объекты), как вызывать функции и как сохранять результат выполнения функций.

Comment: Allocate выделит вам память под контейнер и вернет указатель. А куда вы собрались сохранять этот указатель?

Comment: ну, после того как я запустил без  указания типа, то гда и понял, что надо нечто вроде  
    pointer ptr = std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::allocate()

Comment: весь вопрос был в том что такое qualified-id ? а это я так понял у казания типа, но без указания какой переменной его возвращать.В любом случае спасибо Вам, за очевидную ошибку. Но просто нигде не мог найти что такое qualified-id .

Comment: Ах, вы оказывается, как я и предположил изначально, собирались объявить переменную. Почему вас тогда с самого начала "объявляли пременную" без указания ее имени? Почему вас это сразу не "удивило"? Необходимость объявления переменной однако вызывает сомнения - скорее всего вам нужно сохранять результат в поле класса, а не в локальной переменной. Qualified-id - это имя с `::` внутри. `std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::allocate` - это qualified-id.

Comment: честно говоря, из-за не знания этой ошибки ( qualified-id ) я как-то пропустил это момент и гуглил... гуглил, прочитывал cppreference про allocator_traints, конструкторы  контейнеров... короче говоря, начал копать да нетуда. ошибка дурацкая.... но не зная переводу получилось совсем глупо... Но теперь после вашего ликбеза, я думаю все получится. еще раз большое Вам спасибо